# Is there a way to edit mongo db sorting?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose collection that sorts by first added, and I want it to sort by last edited

The model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var user = require("./user");

var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 text: String,
  asked: String,
  answer: String
 })

module.exports = mongoose.model("question", questionSchema);
```

The put request code:

```
router.put("/:user/:id", checkOwner, function(req, res){
 question.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.question, function(err, 
 updatedQuestion){
  if(err) {
   console.log(err);
   } else {
    res.redirect("/");
   }
  });
});
```

I want that updatedQuestion to be on the top my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple approach:
First you have to add `timestamps` in your mongoose model, in order to have access on `createdAt` and `updatedAt` proerties.
You can see more about timestamps [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var user = require("./user");

var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 text: String,
  asked: String,
  answer: String
 },
{ timestamps: true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("question", questionSchema);
```

Then you can query your collections, applying sorting by `updatedAt`

```
question.find({}, {}, {sort: { 'updatedAt' : -1 }})
```

Thus the most recent updated document will be shown first.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

question.find({asked: req.params.user.toString()}, function(err, questions){
        res.render("user", {questions: questions, user: user, username: req.params.user.toString()});
      }, {sort: { 'updatedAt' : -1 }}) 
is that how it's supposed to look?

Edit: tried using it as a promise .sort({ 'updatedAt' : -1 }) and it worked
Thanks for the help I didn't know about time stamps before